# Use ASP.NET to e-mail contents of an entire HTML Page?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, email

I have a HTML page that I have created that essentially consists of:

```
<div>
   <table>
       <tr>
          <td><asp:label runat="server" id="someText"></asp:label></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

The label text is generated on page load from an SQL query.

The above is a very basic and simplified version of what I have on my page.

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to e-mail the entirety of the rendered HTML page without having to build the page again in my code-behind to send it.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe (haven't tested):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb));

this.Render(hw);

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = sb.ToString();

(new SmtpClient()).Send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the email as you render the page, without rerunning the page lifecycle, try the following.

Make a wrapper stream class that inherits `Stream` and contains two additional streams, and override its `Write` method to write to both streams.  I don't think you need to override anything else except the Can_Whaterver_ properties, but I'm not sure.

Make a field in your Page class of type `MemoryStream` to hold a copy of the response.

Then, handle the page's `PreInit` event and set the [`Response.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx), like this:

```
Response.Filter = new CopierStream(Response.Filter, responseCopy);
//`CopierStream` is the custom stream class; `responseCopy` is the MemoryStream
```

Finally, override the Page's `Render` method, and, after calling `base.Render`, you can send `responseCopy` by email using the [`SmtpClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).

This is a very complicated technique that you should only do if you *really* don't want to re-run the page lifecycle.

---

Whichever way you do it, if your page has any images or hyperlinks, make sure that their urls include the domain name, or else they won't work in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webclient:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
Dim str As String = wc.DownloadString("yoururl.com")
SendEmail(str) ' your email method '
```

Comment: +1 this would work, if the page is valid html, email clients are picky about the HTML in the body of an email... (css and js files are usually not too well accepted...

Comment: Just for explain, various e-mail clients do not execute javascript very well. They almos always ignore all the coding. Some Css is ok if you embbed then in the page instead of referencing.