# Send ASP.NET page in email

Tags: asp.net, html, email

I have an ASP.NET form that is fairly intensive (~100 ASP.NET controls).  I need to accept the input from the user, and then when they click submit, have the form be emailed to a specified email address.  The thing is that I need to submit the form as it appears on the web page.  Does anyone have a simple solution for automatically converting the ASP.NET into pure HTML so that I can insert it into an email?

Comment: I think this other question solves your problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329254/use-asp-net-to-e-mail-contents-of-an-entire-html-page

Answer (score 0):

you need to add whole HTML code of your webpage in smtp emails subject including user input.